# Spring Cloud Data Flow: using filter as processor

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I started to lean Spring Cloud Data Flow and trying to create a simple definition:

```
 dataflow:> stream create --name filtertest --definition "read_file: file | filter --expression=payload=='Amount' | write_file: file" --deploy
```

At the entrance stream read the file with following data:

```
1.Date;
2.Operation;
3.Amount;
4.Item_of_expenditure;
5.Balance;
```

I don't understand, how filter will handle this data:

1. It pass to sink only "Amount", which was read from file;
2. It pass to sink the whole data from file *in case*, if file contains "Amount"

Answer (score 1):

The filter processor filters the records that pass the filter expression criteria. It sends the entire payload (say the line that it received from the file source - depending on how the file source is configured) of the record that matches filtering criteria.

It is typically not the while file as a payload instead it would be each record in it - of course it depends on how you configure the file source.